# How to show selected columns from a datagrid that is bound to a list of objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I have a datagrid to display a dataset that i grab from an API service. Currently, the datagrid display the entire dataset. However, i only wish to display selected columns. Setting
AutoGenerateColumns="False" option and than add in the columns to display give the following error  "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.'" due to the collection should not exist yet before i run the program. I do not wish to hide or delete columns from the dataset as well. What method do i use to display those desired columns.

XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Dataset}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="A"
                          Binding="{Binding a}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="B"
                          Binding="{Binding b}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="D"
                          Binding="{Binding d}"/>
</DataGrid>
```

where Dataset:

```
var Dataset = await_apiDataService.GetDataSet();

            if (Dataset != null)
            {
                Dataset.Clear();
                foreach (var item in Dataset)
                {
                    Dataset.Add(item);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate class with exactly the fields that you want to display

```
var response = await_apiDataService.GetDataSet();

if (response != null)
{
    var dataVMs = response.Select(t=> new DataViewModel{ }).ToList();
    Dataset.Clear();
    Dataset.AddRange(dataVMs);
}

class DataViewModel 
{
    //Add fields here

}
```

Or you can change your xaml to use `ListView` instead of `DataGrid` and then style the listview template accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can not add columns directly to DataGrid. you have to add them to DataGrid.Columns property:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Dataset}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="A" Binding="{Binding a}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="B" Binding="{Binding b}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="D" Binding="{Binding d}"/>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```